# Arcpy in Python Plugin for SPSS

Tags: python, arcpy, installation, cursor, spss

Is it possible to run the arcpy module in the Python for SPSS plugin to run the search and update cursors?

Comment: In V22 of SPSS you can point the Python location to an alternative directory as long as it is the same version of python (2.7), but you need to make sure to match bit versions. (I could test - but I have always had the fortune to have 64 bit SPSS and of course 32 bit ArcGIS).

Comment: I am running v22 of spss (64 bit).  Do I have to run the import sys sys.path.append command?

Comment: No, you can just change the location through the menus. Edit -> Options -> File Locations. I don't believe there is native command syntax to do this.

Comment: So it seems the Python Location is greyed out.  A google search does not yield any interesting results on how to solve

Comment: I doubt the Python install with ArcGIS is 64 bit - so if you have 64 bit SPSS that won't work anyway.

Comment: I reinstalled everything......ArcGIS 10.2.2, python 2.7.6 (x64) and spss 22 x64.  I did notice that ArcGIS 10.2.2 installs python 2.7.5, but I cannot tell if that is x32 or x64.  I would assume x32 as you mentioned above.  Spss also installs its own python, but I cannot tell if it is 32 or 64.  Before I installed either SPSS or ArcGIS, I installed the python x64.  Would that make a difference?  Update:  SPSS 22 installs python 2.7.1, but no documentation on 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: As of V22 SPSS comes automatically installed with Python, and its version will match your SPSS version. Maybe you can try to download [Geoprocessing for 64 bit](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/12/python-scripting-with-64-bit-processing/) and see if you can point SPSS's python to that location.

Comment: ok I got it to work this way:  I directed the SPSS 22 to the ArcGIS x64 python folder.  All features seem to work including the spss and other python modules.  Note:  to change the library, you have to go to file locations and change it only when you do nto have nay other data open...I was trying that before and it did not work.